# How to set correct search weight

Tags: magento2

I created a new attribute: **tags**

here I assign example: sneakers men and set search weight 10
In second attribute I created `brand` and here I set weight 9

Now When I search for example: Sneakers men Nike should display only products with these tags/attributes.

But Magento displays first these products and when it displays these products with these attributes, after this it also displays a lot of other products not related to the search. How to solve it?

Any solution on how to set the correct search engine?